# Wordpress default Search function inconsistent in WooCommerce Product Titles

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, query, search

I have a custom query searching by Post title keyword for WooCommerce. But some words return no results and some words do. This simple query doesn't return all words.

**Words that work:**
Dressing
Square
Sterile

**Words that do not work:**
Promogran
Oasis
Silver
Drawtex

```
      /* Get all Products by keyword*/
      $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      's' => $prodkeywords
      );

   $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // Posts are found
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
           $the_query->the_post();
            global $post;

         /* Return Results Here */


        endwhile;
    }
```

Comment: What does `$prodkeywords` contain?  Is is a single keyword from your list above? An array of keywords?  A string with multiple words?  Also, is there a reason you are referencing the Global $post?  Seems like you'd want to get a post from your current loop.  That would be `$myPost = get_the_post();`  ... Might be able to help diagnose, once you've clarified `$prodkeywords`.

Comment: @MikeBaxter - Yes, the $prodkeywords would be a simple word like "Oasis", and a few of our products would be something like "HA62363 Oasis Latex Gloves 50 CT" or something of that nature. Then if someone searches for "Latex" it would show results, but not for "Oasis" for some reason.

Comment: The reason I am using this query is that I am returning only the ID's of the post. Then I have to do some more checks in an array to compare approved products versus products not authorized. Then I produce a second loop. There is alot more going on than this, but as far as the query goes, I am only using the "s" in the query to find keywords in the title. I am just not getting the results I should at this point in my code. So the other script I use afterwards, isn't really taking away from it.

Comment: So sorry!  Thank you for the additional information. It was very helpful. Unfortunately, the only issue I could find was your referencing `global $post`.  And ... that has nothing to do with the problem for which you are seeking assistance.  If I come up with anything, I will add an Answer, but I have not found anything to explain this.

Comment: @MikeBaxter - Thank you!